# How can I remove the Form Assistant from iOS keyboard?

Tags: ios, delphi, keyboard, firemonkey

When loading the `iOS` keyboard in `Delphi Seattle`, every call to the keyboard reproduces this weird effect on it's Platform Assistant:

[image]

### Steps to reproduce

---

1 - Create a FMX Multiplatform application with an `TEdit`.

2 - Launch your application at your `iOS` device.

3 - Click on `TEdit`.

---

Does anybody have any idea how can we fix it?

This is definately not the way keyboard works on iOS.

I have tested this condition on `iPhone 5`, `iPhone 5s` and `iPhone 6s`.

Comment: *This is definately not the way keyboard works on iOS.* That's one of the drawbacks of using non-native tools to produce apps. FMX isn't consistent with the platform APIs because it tries too hard to use the same codebase for everything rather than harness native support. The drawback to a single codebase across diverse OSes is that you lose the capability to behave like native apps do.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the truth: FMX it's not an native tool. However, I'd rather believe there is always a way to solve things. The bar is called FormAssistant. Maybe there is a way to simply **remove** it? Check this out. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DesigningForms/DesigningForms.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **IFMXVirtualKeyboardToolbarService** service:

```
var
  VKToolbarService: IFMXVirtualKeyboardToolbarService;
begin
  TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardToolbarService, IInterface(VKToolbarService));
if VKToolbarService <> nil then
  VKToolbarService.SetToolbarEnabled(False);
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks!